# Why does it give an error when I call a function as a call by reference with a variable value that has no value?

Tags: c#, function, pass-by-reference

```cs
int x;
Method3(ref x);
Console.WriteLine("x is : {0}", x);
Console.ReadKey();

static void Method3(ref int a)
{
    a += 100;
}
```

I face this error! "Error   CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'x' "

Use that memory location to add to the value of 100

Comment: Tip: always show code as text; images are inaccessible (think: screen reader software), and can't be copy/pasted to work with

Comment: You are facing this error because you are doing exactly what the error says. What if I told you "add 100" - wouldn't you be asking "add to what?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you expect the outcome of that to be, and why? Without knowing the initial value of `x`, this would have undefined behaviour. Locals have ... complicated rules around their initial value. In IL, whether the stackframe is zero'd is optional (and can be configured via attributes in C#). To avoid this problem, C# uses "definite assignment" rules to enforce that the caller has defined a value for locals before that value is observed. So: give `x` a value! Perhaps zero. Then you can add 100 to it and understand the answer.

```cs
int x = 0;
```

This is different to *fields*, as fields have implied zero/null defaults.

---

Note: you *can* suppress this if you really want, to see garbage on the stack. To do that you would add `[SkipLocalsInit]` to the method, and replace `int x;` with `Unsafe.SkipInit(out int x);` (this is a no-op method that is removed by the JIT, but which satisfies C#'s definite assignment rules). I don't see any good use for doing this here, though! These modifiers are intended for very specific performance-critical scenarios far outside of normal language usage, and they're on the understanding that any side-effects are your problem.